# No counter defined error

Tags: errors, compiling

When I try to compile in my laptop a (synced) tex file wich is perfectly compiling in my desktop computer I get the message:

"! LaTeX Error: No counter 'd' defined."

I reinstalled and updated MikTeX and packages, and deleted aux files, but the problem persists.

Does anybody know what can be the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Edit: I think I isolated a bit the problem. A MWE follows:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}

% mypackages.sty

% STANDARD PACKAGES -------------------------------------------------------
%\RequirePackage{../../../_config_LaTeX/my_packages}

% mypackages.sty

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% AMS
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}         % controls figure positions
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{todonotes}


% THEOREMS -------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{defn}
This is a definition.
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Concretely, the issues are:

- If I compile the code like this, it works.
- If I include all the packages in "mypackages.sty", and substitute then by     \RequirePackage{../../../_config_LaTeX/my_packages} then
  I get the error:

  "! LaTeX Error: No counter 'd' defined."
- If I then remove "[thm]" from  "\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}", then it compiles well again.
- I am only having this problem in my laptop, in my desktop computer everything compiles well.

Hope that these indications help.

Comment: Without seeing code this is difficult to tell. I don't know a package or class, that uses `d` as a counter name

Comment: it means you have gone `\setcounter{d}{42}` without going `\newcounter{d}` if you do not get an error on the other computer, it is executing different code.

Comment: But the files are synced, it is strange... it used to work fine in the past (a few moths ago). I have added to the question a reduced version of my preamble to provide some more information.

Comment: @suitangi: Well, you've got 3 files in your document that are not shown to us. If I comment them out, your code runs

Comment: Yes @Christian, I know. Sorry for that (some of them are huge). But the point is that the file (I'll dare to say the exact same file) perfectly compiles in my desktop computer.

Comment: @suitangi: it is quite possible that package versions matters. But without an example that demonstrates the problem *and that we can compile* we can't investigate. Beside this: compare the log-files.

Comment: Should I include in the question the log files corresponding to the compiled and non-compiled attempts?

Comment: Ok @David, I see your point. I will do that. But just in order to know how the site works (I am quite newbie here), is it appropriate to include full log files in the questions?

Comment: unrelated to your question but `\rm` has been deprecated since latex2e came out in 1993, but if you do use it it does not take an argument so the syntax is `{\rm xxx}` not `\rm{xxx]`

Comment: Thank you @David I will take this into account. Related to my question, I think I isolated the error: it is related to the use of shared counters in \newtheorem specifications. The 'd' in my question stands for the "definitions counter". When I remove the shared counter [thm] the file compiles correctly in my laptop. Why can be that this is happening in one computer but not in the other?

Comment: If a counter is defined in one computer but not the other then clearly the code you are executing is not the same on the two machines but you have given absolutely no hint that would allow anyone to help. No one else can do anything with your example with lines like `\RequirePackage{../../../_config_LaTeX/my_tikz}` if you get the error when that is removed, remove it, if you only get the error if that is there then the error is in that file which only you have, in which case show the relevant parts.

Comment: @David I edited the question in order to provide more useful hints. Hope that this helps.

Comment: The MWE runs without error, add `\listfiles` and then run it on the two machines and compare the file lists at the end of each log.

Comment: @David Yes, the MWE also runs without error to me, the problem is when I substitute all the \usepackage commands by the \RequirePackage line (where my_packages.sty content is exactly the list of \usepackages in the MWE).

Comment: Then there is an error in that local file.

Comment: I have a similar issue. In my case, having defintions and theorems share the same counter seems to be the issue. See if getting rid of [thm] for your defn environment allows the file to compile. (I know that this is not a solution.)

Comment: OK, in my case, hyperref seems to be the culprit.